# Deploy Module to App Engine option is not available on Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

In the steps for deploying the backend live to app engine described here :

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

It says to do the following steps in Android Studio :

Run Build > Deploy Module to App Engine

However, in Android Studio 1.0.1, there does not seem to be any option there for deploying module to app engine.

Have the steps in the above link not been updated correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine on 1.0.1 build. You don't even have to have a backend module for the option to show.

[image]

[image]

Do note that it's under the **Build** menu, not under **Run**

Comment: Thanks. I kept looking under Run. I ended up using gradlew api:appengineUpdate as described here : http://rominirani.com/2014/08/25/gradle-tutorial-part-8-gradle-app-engine-endpoints-android-studio/